# Menu does not align correctly in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser

I have created **a menu** with `relative position` to its parent and gave them a `rotate` attribute to make align it as diagonal. It works in Chrome, Firefox and even in IE. But I don't know why it is dislocated horribly in Safari. I tested it in Safari 5.1.7.

I have tried to inspect the element, but can't find the problem. Could you please tell me which CSS code that make this happen?

**Below is the CSS and HTML code:**

```css
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.navbar-static-top {
    border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-static-top {
    z-index: 1000;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
}

.navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}


.container {
    width: 1170px;
}

.container {
    width: 970px;
}

.container {
    width: 750px;
}
.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}


.navbar-header {
    float: left;
    height: 76px;
    display: table;
}


.navbar-default nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}


.navbar-default nav .navbar-nav {
    left: 65%;
}

.navbar-default nav .navbar-nav {
    position: relative;
    left: 60%;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    top: 76px;
    transform-origin: top left;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
}

.navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}


.navbar-default nav .navbar-nav li:nth-child(1) {
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.navbar-default nav .navbar-nav li {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default nav .navbar-nav li {
    border-top: 3px solid #333333;
    border-left: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    float: none;
}
ul li.collapsed, ul li.expanded, ul li.leaf {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
}


.navbar-default nav .navbar-nav li:nth-child(2) {
    z-index: 2;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
}

.navbar-default nav .navbar-nav li:nth-child(3) {
    z-index: 3;
    top: 80px;
    left: 80px;
}

.navbar-default nav .navbar-nav li:nth-child(4) {
    z-index: 4;
    top: 120px;
    left: 120px;
}

.navbar-default nav .navbar-nav li:nth-child(5) {
    z-index: 5;
    top: 160px;
    left: 160px;
}
```

```html
<header id="navbar" role="banner" class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <div class="left-header">
              <a class="logo navbar-btn" href="/" title="Home">
          <img src="http://dxi.dd:8083/sites/all/themes/dxi/images/designx-logo-214.png" alt="Home">
        </a>
                    <div class="date-venue content-a"><div class="content-b">
                <div class="h3">19 - 21 February 2019</div>
                <div class="site-venue">Jakarta International Expo, Jakarta, Indonesia</div></div>
            </div>
                    </div>
      
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
          </div>

          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <nav role="navigation">
                      <ul class="menu nav navbar-nav"><li class="first leaf active"><a href="/" class="active">Home</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/about-trade-show">About</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/why-attend" title="">Attend</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/why-exhibit" title="">Exhibit</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a href="/features" title="">Features</a></li>
</ul>                                      </nav>
      </div>
      </div>
</header>
```

My site is http://dev.designxindonesia.com.

Comment: Show code not link

Answer (score -1):

sometimes `transform` doesn't work well in safari. Try using vendor prefix for webkit. i.e,

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: I did add those code. but that's not the problem i think.